# Is it possible to removeChild and also delete its content from Memory?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am currently dynamically adding images to a div because I am visualizing data. Thus, I am also removing images every 3 seconds. I am currently calling removeChild but it doesn't remove its content from memory. Is there a way to clear up some memory?

Here is some example code: https://jsfiddle.net/eybb9rxc/2/

```
var rightImages = document.getElementById('rightImages');

setInterval(function() { 
    rightImages.removeChild(rightImages.childNodes[0]);
}, 3000);
```

In addition, the childNode also has elements in it. Would I need to loop and call removeChild on every element inside it? Or would calling it once be enough?

Comment: This is somewhat explained in the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/removeChild), where it states that a node without any references, being removed with `removeChild` should be deleted by the GC within a short time.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the element to `null` will enable it for the garbage collector as long as there are no other valid references to that object.

Comment: I thought so. Wasn't sure if there was any other way than the garbage collector. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Memory_Management) any removed items with no remaining references will be trashed by garbage collector. I think setting it `null` will be enough. Please check "Reference-counting garbage collection" section.